# HTML doesn't show php script on Uuntu 12.04 ( PHP5, Apache2, mysql) all are installed properly

Tags: 12.04, apache2, php, mysql, lamp

*But info.php in /var/www/ does show the info.
Only PHP embedded in html doesn't show the script.
please help me..*

**I have tried the previous askubuntu questions and didnot get anything useful so please don't delete the question**

Comment: Have you tried asking or searching it on http://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers". You can even post your code there.

Comment: yeah I searched on stackoverflow but there is no answer

Comment: Edit your question and include the code (am not sure if that will be allowed here) and we shall look at it...

Comment: Are you referring to the scripts as you include within html script or when you do check for the source & inspect element?? Could you please clarify that.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo "My first PHP script!";
?>  

</body>
</html>

Comment: that is my code in index.html file and when i open the file the browser doesnot show the "my first php script" line..

Comment: I have no errors even when i install LAMP

Comment: index.html is the issue, it should be index.php All php files (even html files with inline php) should end with a .php extension.

Comment: Avatar Parto thanks for the solution it worked, But if u are on github, u might have noticed that i doesn't work for github right ? I mean someone.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a note that when you insert a **PHP** script within your **HTML** or supporting file, you will then have to save it as `.php` instead of `.html` or `.htm`

Rename your file to `index.php` or whatever accordingly & try refreshing the content on web browser.

On a related note, make sure that the PHP is up & running in order to process `.php` scripts. :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Glad it worked. You may accept it as an answer if it helped you to further avoid questions being on queue without answered. :)

Comment: Yeah sure, But it doesn't work on github right ?

Comment: i mean personal website like someone.github.io

Comment: I cannot exactly say about github as I've not used it. But generally web scripts will/should support such extensions. Correct me if I'm wrong.